# Why displaying array when select column in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to select a column in mysql in php,

```
function PageController() {

$data = [
    'categories'    => _db_get_select("categories", ['name'])

];
load_view("tutu", $data);
```

and

```
function _db_get_select($table_name, $columns) {
$servername = _c("database.server_name");
$username = _c("database.username");
$password = _c("database.password");
$dbname = _c("database.db_name");

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
// echo "Connected successfully";

$sql = "SELECT name=$columns FROM  . $table_name.";
    var_dump($sql);
```

the result is displaying like this

> string(42) "SELECT ['name']=Array FROM . categories."

I want to be like this

> SELECT name FROM . categories.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this script

```
function PageController() {
$data = [
    'categories'    => _db_get_select("categories", "name")
];
load_view("tutu", $data);
```

And the function  will be

```
function _db_get_select($table_name, $columns) {
$servername = _c("database.server_name");
$username = _c("database.username");
$password = _c("database.password");
$dbname = _c("database.db_name");
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
 $sql = "SELECT {$columns} FROM  {$table_name}";
}
```

Comment: it worked bro, can u tell me why i can't use array like ['name']; instead of "name",anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just echo your sql variable instead of var dump like below

```
echo $sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach loop to iterate through an array of columns to form a query.

```
function PageController() {
    $data = array('categories' => _db_get_select("categories", array("name")));
    load_view("tutu", $data);
}
```

And then:

```
//Start with select
$sql = 'SELECT ';

//Concat column names separated with commas
foreach ($columns as $value) {
     $sql .= $value . ', ';
}

//Get rid of the last comma
$sql = rtrim($sql, ', ');

$sql .= ' FROM ' . $table_name;
```

Check if it's okey:

```
var_dump($sql);
```

Comment: why are u using double array sir , i dun get it .

Comment: It allows me to pass much more data to your function. For example, i could do `_db_get_select("categories", array("name" => "tech"))` and then if you modify your function, it would return all categories whose name contains "tech". In other words, you can implement WHERE statement.